# 3D Model .fbx to .gftl conversion

Tags: animation, 3d-modeling, 3ds-max, maya

I am unable to convert my 3D object file, created on 3d max, into gftl format? Actually, while trying to convert, the material of the .fbx or .obj files is not reflected in the .gftl format?

Comment: Which application are you using to convert?

Comment: Tried some online converters? for example - scapic.com

Comment: This is a long-pending issue actually. And I just don't know how to get the missing material file (.mtl), the whole project was made in 3ds max. .fbx and .obj versions when are exported gives a negative result.